# How does the browser handle Javascript variable scope?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application that has several script tags.

Suppose I have a variable called *customPage* within the tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customPage = callSomeFunction();
<script>

Elsewhere in the page...

<script type="text/javascript">
    var customPage = callSomeOtherFunction();
<script>
```

What is the scope of these JavaScript variables, since they are all defined using the same name? Will they overwrite each other? Or do they all have value within their own scope?

Comment: Partial views should not contain scripts.

Comment: head over to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) question

Comment: My answer is no longer valid after your edit, because your variables are now inside function invocations. Each function has its own local variables.

Comment: So each call to jquery init $(function () {}) then has its own scope? Because each is an anonymous function?

Comment: The new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285662/how-does-the-jquery-document-ready-function-handle-variable-scoping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables declared at the 'top' level of a `<script>` element are part of the [Global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) JavaScript object. In web browsers, this makes them properties of the `window` object.

Whichever code is run second will overwrite the value of the variable from the first code sample.

```html
<script>
var foo = "hello";
console.log(foo, window.foo);
</script>

<script>
var foo = "world";
console.log(foo, window.foo);
</script>
```

The above code snippet shows:

```
hello hello
world world
```

(Which also shows that you could have tested out the answer to this question yourself. [TIAS!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tias))

Comment: What is the best practice for keeping variables in a web page? Suppose I have several div tags that represent tables on my page, but each table contains a specific javascript object called TableDataManager. How would I keep track of each table's TableDataManager instance?

Comment: @JoseChavez Don't use global variables? Store JS objects associated with each element as an expando property on the element itself? It's hard to advise without knowing more details.

Comment: @JoseChavez To give a general answer, use a project named object, like `var myproj = { foo: 'hello', bar: 'world'}`

Comment: Updated my question with more details.

Comment: FYI, what you did was over-simplified your question and asked the wrong one. You've now changed your question to one that has a very different answer.

Comment: @JoseChavez I recommend you roll back the edit and ask a new question with the new requirements

Comment: Thanks for the input; created new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285662/how-does-the-jquery-document-ready-function-handle-variable-scoping)

Comment: You are right, I could have TIAS :) But I would not have known about the global window object, and how global variables become members of the window object!